# Hosting R Shiny application

Tags: html, r

A conventional website architecture
has separate html files for each page. For example,
"About Us" page has about.html and "Contact Us" has
contact.html. Similarly, the home page has "index.html".

Along similar lines, how can i locate the html pages
for a R Shiny application that I have build. The reason
I ask is because instead of publishing my R Shiny application
on a R Shiny server, i need to host it using my own
server.

Alternatively, can i embed my R Shiny application on a different website?

I would appreciate if you can kindly help me in this regard.

thanks,
bhaskar